# Create a pandas column based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame like this:

```
Group Col A Col B
  1    A1    B1
  1    A2    B2
  2    A3    B3
  2    A4    B4
```

I want to create a new columns Per A and Per B respecting grouops, so the outcome should be

```
Group Col A Col B     Per A           Per B
  1    A1    B1   100*A1/(A1+A2)  100*B1/(B1+B2)
  1    A2    B2   100*A2/(A1+A2)  100*B2/(B1+B2)
  2    A3    B3   100*A3/(A3+A4)  100*B3/(B3+B4)
  2    A4    B4   100*A4/(A3+A4)  100*B4/(B3+B4)
```

I need a general case, with several groups each of which having different group sizes.

I tried using a for loop, and while I am able to find the columns, I cannot assign them to the data frame. I don't understand what is exactly that prevents it.

For example, this is a result I'd be looking for (note how I change the Group column reflecting "different group sizes")

```
Group Col A Col B Per A Per B
  1     1     2   100.0 100.0
  2     1     2   16.67 25.00
  2     2     2   33.33 25.00
  2     3     4   50.00 50.00
```

Comment: kindly provide actual data, with expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2):

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Group': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
        'ColA': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'ColB': [10,22,30,40,50,60,70],
    })
 
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['Group'])['ColA', 'ColB'].sum().reset_index(), 
              left_on='Group', right_on='Group')
df['PerA'] = df['ColA_x']*100/df['ColA_y']
df['PerB'] = df['ColB_x']*100/df['ColB_y']

df = df.rename(
    columns={'ColA_x': 'ColA', 'ColB_x': 'ColB'}).drop(
        columns=['ColA_y', 'ColB_y'])

print (df)
```

output:

```
   Group  ColA  ColB       PerA       PerB
0      1     1    10  33.333333  31.250000
1      1     2    22  66.666667  68.750000
2      2     3    30  42.857143  42.857143
3      2     4    40  57.142857  57.142857
4      3     5    50  27.777778  27.777778
5      3     6    60  33.333333  33.333333
6      3     7    70  38.888889  38.888889
```

Comment: It seems that need to find percentages first and then update my dataframe. I am able to find the percentages using group by and division, but trying to update the dataframe failed. Also, my data frame has several groups and several columns A, B, .... which makes this solution unpleasant. Yet, this is similar to what I was already trying to do originally.

Answer (score 2):

Groupby group and then sum. That gives you the colum sum per group.

Set group as index and then divide by the outcome above. index makes it possible to only divide similar index terms. Code below

```
df.set_index('group').div(df.groupby('group').sum())*100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby` `transform` with `update`

```
df.update(df.div(df.groupby('Group').transform('sum'))*100)
df
Out[478]: 
   Group       ColA       ColB
0      1  33.333333  31.250000
1      1  66.666667  68.750000
2      2  42.857143  42.857143
3      2  57.142857  57.142857
4      3  27.777778  27.777778
5      3  33.333333  33.333333
6      3  38.888889  38.888889
```

Comment: All the answers seem to produce the percentages first and then add the columns later. I guess there is no work around to update the current dataframe in place.